# dnssec remove keys from zone

Tags: bind, dnssec, rndc

is there a way to remove all dnssec related stuff from a zone on a running  bind server?

I configured bind like [like here described](https://deepthought.isc.org/article/AA-00711/0/In-line-Signing-With-NSEC3-in-BIND-9.9-A-Walk-through.html).

If i use `rndc signing -clear all domain.tld` nothng happens to the zone.

If i delete the dnssec signed zone via `rndc delzone domain.tld`
and recreate it via `rndc addzone domain.tld ...` , the `domain.tld.jnl` file with the related dnssec data will be automaticly recreated and the zone is dnssec signed again.

**How can i remove all dnssec related data from a zone with rndc ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i use the inline-signing option to auto sign the zones in another file called `{Zonename}.signed`)

To remove all DNSSEC related Data of the Zone u have to remove the `{ZoneName}.signed` and `{ZoneName}.jnl` file of the Zone.

Remove also all the Key Files of the Zone (which should be in the [`keys` - Directory](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/hkpng.html#key-directory)) - otherwhise bind9 will autoresign the Zone.

After all the deletion it would be the clear way to `rndc delzone {ZoneName}` and reinititate the unsigned Zone with `rndc addzone {Options without DNSSEC}`